# Incomplete list of jobs using getAllItems API call

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm using following code snippet to retrieve job list in a [Jenkins plugin](https://github.com/arcadien/bitbucket-plugin) :

```
SecurityContext old = ACL.impersonate(ACL.SYSTEM);
for (AbstractProject<?, ?> job : Jenkins.getInstance()
                        .getAllItems(AbstractProject.class)) {

// useful work on jobs

}
SecurityContextHolder.setContext(old);
```

Unfortunately, not all jobs are processed through the loop, according to the Jenkins logs.
I have Maven and FreeStyle jobs, only a few of them are discarded. The filter "AbstractProject.class", according to class hierarchy, should return everything.
Could someone point out documentation or something i'm missing? thanks by advance

Comment: Probably you should consider within which user you run the plugin. Probably that user has insufficient rights?

Comment: Right. I update the snippet : i'm using impersonation to run under the SYSTEM identity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the bug with a refactoring of the loop :

```
SecurityContext old = ACL.impersonate(ACL.SYSTEM);
for (AbstractProject<?, ?> job : Jenkins.getInstance()
                        .getAllItems(AbstractProject.class)) {

// useful work on jobs

}
SecurityContextHolder.setContext(old);
```

with :

```
ACL.impersonate(ACL.SYSTEM, new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        for (AbstractProject<?, ?> job : Jenkins.getInstance()
                                .getAllItems(AbstractProject.class)) {

                            try {

                                processJob(job, remote, scm);

                            } catch (Exception jobProcessingException) {
                                LOGGER.severe("Something bad occured processing job "
                                        + job.getName());
                                jobProcessingException.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this hint about impersonalization. My code to invoke a job from init.groovy.d/ after restart was not working: job search was returning null. ACL usage helped.